# Como crear una lista desplegables con submenu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Buen dia ,
Estoy tratando de crear una lista desplegable con submenu's dentro al momento de hacer y correrlo no me deja hacerlo , no me lo muestra, lo estoy haciendo con boostrap 3.3.7 que viene en el mvc 5 de VB, me podria ayudar como poder hacerlo

[image: Asi se tendria que ver]

este es parte de mi codigo:

```html
 <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Test<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" >
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-menu-right" data-toggle="dropdown"><a>Test1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <li class="dropdown">Test1_1</li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>Test2<b class="caret"></b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Podrías subir tu código HTML que tienes con bootstrap para ver cuál es el problema?

Comment: @HugoQuiñónez listo ya lo anexe. saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los submenus no están disponibles en la versión 3 de Bootstrap, pero puedes agregarlos al CSS

```css
.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
}
```

Puedes ver el uso de distintos sub niveles en [este ejemplo](https://www.codeply.com/go/ji5ijk6yJ4)

Comment: Esta pregunta fue tratada y respondida exahustivamente en SO. Ver [Bootstrap dropdown sub menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-dropdown-sub-menu-missing). Las explicaciones ofrecidas allí son muy importantes y conviene leerlas.

Comment: Gracias por el dato @quevedo.