# Boostrap 4 Ayuda con dropdown button

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Estoy estudiando angular 9 pero a la vez quiero aprender Bootstrap 4, estoy estancado en el siguiente problema:

Tengo un dropdown button que no me funciona y en el curso que sigo usan bootstrap 3 entonces debo solucionar por mi cuenta, agregué un snippet que encontré de ejemplo en la documentacion de bootstrap 4 pero no funciona, aparece el boton pero no despliega las opciones dentro como si pasa en ejemplo en la pagina de bootstrap, cualquier idea que me ayude a solucionar esto estaré muy agradecido.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img style="max-height: 200px;" [src]=" model.imagePath " alt="{{model.name}} " class="img-thumbnail ">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            <h4>{{ model.name }}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Manage
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            {{model.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            Models
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: En Angular Tienes que descargar el npm de Bootstrap y también el ngx de Bootstrap y de ahí ir al creo era angular.json y agregar los scripts de css y js, o por otro lado, usar los cdn del css y el Js

Comment: El drop-down have uso del de ngx, busca en internet como Bootstrap Angular, hay una página que recopila los códigos para adaptar Bootstrap con Angular

Comment: Pedron Rocha, gracias por tu comentario, ya agregué Bootstrap al proyecto,  y lo importe en my style.css, ya me habia enontrado con problemas de diferencia entre el curso que estoy siguiendo y los he solucionado facil pero esta vez no esta funcionando.

Comment: El asunto es que el dropdown requiere un import d'El ngx Bootstrap

Comment: A que te refieres como lo hago?

Comment: import { NgbDropdown} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Comment: This NgbDropdown works for angular 9?

Comment: Estoy teniendo este error ahora: `This likely means that the library (ngx-bootstrap/dropdown) which declares BsDropdownModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version 
of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.`

Comment: Al parecer aun no es compatible con angular 9

Comment: Los dropdowns de Bootstrap 3 ya no existen en la version 4 de Bootstrap, mira esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/302732/83304

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas ya lo pude solucionar, al parecer tenia problemas con los imports que tengo de bootstrap y javascript, los elimine todos del archivo styles.css, del angular.json y los referencie directamente en el index y ya me funciona todo. Muchas gracias nuevamente.